# Rails: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is my controller file belov. As you see I defined create, index, show and edit methods.

```
    class PeopleController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!
#before_action :people_params
before_action :exist_or_not, except:[:show, :index, :edit]


  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  def show
    @person = Person.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def index

  end

  def edit
  @person = Person.find_by(id: params[:id])

  end


def update
  @person = Person.find_by_id(params[:id])
   if @person.update_attributes(people_params)
    flash[:success] = 'person was updated!'
    redirect_to person_edit_path
    else
    render 'edit'
    end
  end

 def create

 if Person.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)
        flash[:warning] = 'you have already details!'
      redirect_to root_path

 else
   @person = current_user.build_person(people_params)
    if @person.save
      flash[:success] = 'person was created!'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
 end


  end





private

def people_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:gender, :birthday, :country_id,:country_name,:state_id, :lang, :id, :user_id)

end


def exist_or_not

    if Person.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)
        flash[:warning] = 'you have already details!'
      redirect_to root_path

    end
end

end
```

Also I shared my _form.html.erb file belov.

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :birthday %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :birthday, :start_year=>1950, :end_year=>2005 %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
   <%= f.radio_button(:gender, "male") %>
<%= f.label(:gender_male,   "Male") %>
<%= f.radio_button(:gender, "female") %>
<%= f.label(:gender_female, "Female") %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>



  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state_id, "State or Province" %><br />
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :state_id, Country.order(:name), :states, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>

<%= f.select :lang, collection: LanguageArray::AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES.sort.map {|k,v| [v,k]} %>


  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

Problem is:
I can create and show people but edit. I cannot open the edit path or page.

"First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Error output screnshot is : [Click for Error output for browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vgDt.png)

Please help me about this error. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_by` returns `nil` when there's nothing found, so `@person` is `nil` thus this error.

For actions on an object like show/edit/update/etc. it's better to use `Person.find(params[:id])`, it will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` when object is not found (later it will be handled as http error 404).

As for why there's no object - check that url is generated correctly and `params[:id]` contains corresponding id (for example you might pass other object's id to urlhelper, which results in a correctly looking url that leads nowhere).

Also you're probably missing parameter to `person_edit_path`

Comment: Thanks dear! i changed the parameters as you said and it is working now. It created new problem but nothing. I reached the point which i want. thanks again.